# Automatic Update to Microsoft Graph API Subscription

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-webhooks

I have created webhook project with Microsoft Graph API to monitor Office 365 inbox.

I made a UpdateSubscription action method which renews it for 3 days only as according to the documentation provide on https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscription

Below is the code snippet of how I'am facilitating the HTTP request to update the subscription

```
        AuthenticationResult authResult = await AuthHelper.GetAccessTokenAsync();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Build the request.
        string subscriptionsEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/"+id;
        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, subscriptionsEndpoint);

        //get the current time

        var subscription = new Subscription
        {
            //Id = id,
            ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4230, 0)
        };
```

Is there a way to auto update without the user pressing the button to 'update'?

since the authorization-headers requires AuthResult.accessToken which will require the user to sign in to Office365 account.

Please advice

Comment: I was able to update the subscription of the user by retrieving the 'RefreshToken' from the HttpRuntimeCache which is used to get the access token using the following method GetAccessTokenFromRefreshTokenAsync. However upon performing a app restart the the cache will not have the 'RefreshToken'. Is it safe to store this in a Database

Answer (score 1):

An option available to you is the service or daemon approach (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only).  Instead of authenticating with a logged-in user you're able to renew the subscription at the application level using a Bearer token which is in turn generated by the CLIENT_SECRET from Azure AD.

I don't think storing tokens in the database is the right approach here.  My understanding is that security tokens are never appropriate for a database.

In fact, I don't quite understand the need to have the user log in at all here, unless there are parts to the program that you didn't mention.  A service like the one I mentioned can monitor a mailbox without a user being there, or else if the program requires the user to be there, there really isn't an issue of lost credentials.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can use this approach to fetch accesstoken from azure using grant_type a password. PLease find the below screenshot.